# Accessing class fields using a variable set to that class

Tags: c#

I have a situation in which I have a class called `myClasses` and two sub classes called `subOne` and `subTwo`.

```
class myClasses
{
    class subOne 
    {
       public const SOfieldOne = "blahblah";
       public const SOfieldTwo = "blahblahblah";
    }

    class subTwo 
    {
       public const STfieldOne = "blahblah";
    }
}
```

I want to be able to set a variable to either class `subOne` or `subTwo` based on an argument passed to one of my methods. I then want to be able to access the members within `subOne` or `subTwo` using this general variable.

For example if the argument is "useSubOne" I want to set a variable `subToUse` as so...

```
subToUse = myClasses.subOne;
```

I should then be able to access `SOfieldOne` by typing the following...

```
subToUse.SOfieldOne
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Well, first off, you don't have *variables*, you have *constants*.  You'll need actual *variables* to even get started.

Comment: I know that I can reference the field using the following statement... myClasses.subOne.SOfieldOne , I don't see why there wouldn't be a way to do this with a variable pointing to the sub class?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish. Can you give us some more context, perhaps with a real use-case, instead of an abstracted one?

Comment: @codingManiac Because variables point to _data_, not _classes_.  You can use reflection to obtain a class from data but not as directly as you think it ought to be.

Comment: @codingManiac That's irrelevant to my point.  Your classes have no variables.  There is nothing for you to access within those classes at runtime.  They are empty.  You'll need to actually have variables/fields to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) does not apply to constants. Here's how your code could look like instead:

```
private class myClasses
{
    private class subOne
    {
        public virtual string SOfieldOne
        {
            get { return "blahblah"; }
        }
    }

    private class subTwo : subOne
    {
        public override string SOfieldOne
        {
            get { return "something else"; }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can create a new variable like this:

```
subOne someVariable = new subTwo();
Console.WriteLine(someVariable.SOfieldOne); // Prints "something else"
```